# Where would it make sense for Presidential candidates to campaign, assuming that the US moves away from the Electoral College system?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

A lot of ink has been spilled on the issue of the Electoral College and how it reduces the election campaign to a few swing States. But what if the system was overhauled tomorrow to a simple first-past-the-post vote? Where would politicians start to campaign in order to maximize their odds?

Note that this isn't primarily opinion based as there are plenty of other democracies with nation-wide voting for a given position.

Comment: I think I asked a similar question a year or so ago.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm you did: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16449/would-abolishing-the-electoral-college-mean-extremist-voters-play-more-of-a-role

Comment: NYC, Chicago and LA.

Comment: Too many variables (influence and penetration of mass media, for example, demographics, changes to the campaign organization to react to the new rules, etc...) to make this answerable, IMO. Maybe they chose a few locations of each region so nobody feels ignored. Maybe they aim for the biggest concentrations of people. Maybe they just rely in mass media. Maybe it becomes a decentraliced campaign as before TV/radio, with more presence of local members of the party. Maybe...

Comment: @SJuan76 you can easily answer this by looking at campaigns in large democracies with a nation-wide vote for president.

Comment: Commentary on this subject often assumes that large cities would dominate. I'd be interested to see an answer which looks at the population of cities vs rural areas in the US, and any related trends.

Comment: I saw an article in *Le Monde* during the french presidential campaign,
and it said that the candidates mostly campaigned in big cities, but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: Perhaps you can outline why you think this is factually answerable.

Comment: I would say "on television" but the real answer is that electoral fraud would determine all elections.  Illinois, California, and other states with Democrat secretaries of state would all simply certify they counted a hundred billion votes with 100% for the Democrat.  Then the dark times would begin.

Comment: The assumption (abolish EC) is never going to happen. Therefore the question is purely hypothetical and should be closed.

Comment: @Distic The answer might be different in America because large cities tend to be overwhelmingly Democratic. Republicans wouldn't waste money there because they would be unlikely to sway anyone. Democrats wouldn't spend money there to convince people to favor them but they might spend money on get-out-the-vote efforts.

Comment: @Joe Yes, one of the reasons eliminating the EC would be a problem lies in how to handle close elections. Imagine the Florida recount having to be done in all 50 states plus DC.

Comment: @Readin wouldn't just apply to "close ones".  Most Democrat-run states have no voter ID requirement and many are actively offering "sanctuary" from law enforcement to illegal aliens.  Best guess is over 30 million illegal aliens, many of them voting.  Currently this kind of activity is "compartmentalized" by the electoral college -- sure it's easy for them to cheat in Blue states, but it doesn't affect elections much unless they do it in Red states, and that's hard.

Comment: @Readin I’m not saying it is the same, but that’s the closest you can get. And in France too the big cities and the countryside have political differences. That’s a shame I can’t find this article

Comment: @Joe if we eliminate the EC, then an election that is very close, say the difference between winner and loser is 1000 votes nationally, would have to be recounted nationally. In 2000 the recount was limited to Florida because a recount in say, California, that changed 10000 votes wouldn't have made a difference in the election outcome.

Comment: @Distic It does make sense to campaign in the cities more than the countryside if you think your odds of getting votes in each place are the same. It is cheaper to reach people in denser areas.

Comment: @Readin: Yes, and usually there are better connexions from the big cities to the countryside and conversely than from the countryside to the countryside. So it may be more efficient to campaign in the big cities **even when** your voters live in the countryside.

Comment: @Sjoerd : according to your reasonning, should we also close all questions about libertarian society or about fully-communist economy ?

Comment: "as there are plenty of other democracies with nation-wide voting for a given position" - the degree to which "campaigning" (in the sense of the candidate personally appearing in front of a crowd) is a significant and/or central part of the period before an election may be different between countries.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption relies on a constitutional amendment which would devalue the input of a majority of states and would never pass. However, IF it were to happen, the most likely strategy would be to campaign where you reach the largest number of uncommitted voters and/or where you get the most free media publicity.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at other countries which implement... normal (?) voting: candidates almost campaign everywhere. (They cannot campaign literally everywhere due to obvious reasons.)

It doesn't make sense to campaign for just 50% or some arbitrary percentage of the country's population. If some candidate campaigned, say, only in the five biggest cities, or even the fifty biggest ones, they certainly wouldn't get elected. Indeed, some inhabitants of these cities will never vote for the candidate, so even if these cities represent 50% of the population it wouldn't ensure a win. Electors outside these cities will feel insulted and will vote against the candidate, even if the candidate is politically aligned with them.